# add meta tag in each template dynamically meteor Platforms

Tags: meteor

Hye,
I want to add dynamically meta tag in each template from my router.js.
I need help please.
the Platform is meteor js

Comment: Are you using a package like Iron Router to do you routing? and can you show your router.js code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add different tags to the `<head>`. And this can be changed on a per page basis.

There are two ways to do this:
1) Using a package, such as:
https://atmospherejs.com/manuelschoebel/ms-seo

2) Using Server side rendering, such as:
https://docs.meteor.com/packages/server-render.html